# VB6 Mod function gives incorrect values with negative values

Tags: vb6, modulo

I have a step in a script in vb6 that is failing.  the code is as follows

```
output = ((azmnum + steps ) mod 16777216)
```

the values the variables in the function are

```
-850344 = (5184326 + -6034670) mod 16777216)
```

All variables are long numbers.  all other programs I enter these values into (python and excel) return 15926872. I can't figure out why the modulo is being ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mod is not the same in all languages, especially for negative numbers.  VB6 (and a whole load of other compilers like C, C++, C#, Java) takes the Fortran interpretation which is the remainder after dividing.  Mathematically, this is the wrong interpretation if the number is negative.  What you have is

```
5184326 + -6034670 = -850344
-850344 mod 16777216 = -850344
```

Python and excel take the correct interpretation of modulo where the result is always positive.  This takes an extra step i.e.

```
-850344 + 16777216 = 15926872
```

Comment: ha, that caught me off guard that the remainder of -850344 / 2^24  is -850344.  Thanks.

Comment: No, unfortunately there isn't one.  Like C, C#, Java and Fortran, the modulo operator in vb6 is only correct for positive numbers.  You'd have to check if the result was negative and add the mod value.